# Disputed audit - Current standard for hashing users password and storing in SQLite database

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Consider:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15729838* on *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791325/current-standard-for-hashing-users-password-and-storing-in-sqlite-database*.

This question *can* be answered concisely and objectively [as I did in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42791325/#comment73455226_42791325).

The problem is also not specific to the storage medium so the "SQLite" part plays no role and can be ignored.

Comment: Your comment is just a link to an answer elsewhere, which *isn't* an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Servy the answer here is: "the standard constantly changes, so you need to consult a dedicated entity each time". The link is but an illustration of one current standard.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question though.  It's just saying that a proper answer is beyond your capacity to include it in an answer, which of course means that the question merits closure.  Again, your answer is, "go here to get your answer" and [that's not an acceptable answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381)

Comment: It's not a great class of question really - we could have hundreds if not thousands of these answered with essentially the same thing. _What's the current standard for OAuth?_ Same answer, different link. _What's the current standard for foo?_ Same answer, different link. The answers will need to be maintained constantly to ensure the "current standard" aspect is still relevant, and that sort of question doesn't suit the format

Comment: The question is really opinion-based. *...and reading a few articles I get the opinion...* *...there is nothing wrong with...* *... Am I wrong?" It's also too broad, because explaining the current state of cryptography would take, well, at least a blog post.

Comment: @Clive your comment is worthy to be an answer, it summarizes the matter pretty well.

Comment: Just close as too locali...ah, dammit

Comment: @Servy the link is only an illustration: "this is how it is (was) at the time of this writing". It's not supposed to stay current. The answer is - "there isn't a specific set of methods stable enough to be worth being copied here, but there are rolling-release specs that you can find like so and so". It addresses the core of the matter and doesn't change with time - so I don't see how it's not a "proper answer". Clive explained what else is wrong here, so I no longer argue it should stay open, but your line of reasoning isn't sound.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Again, it's not an acceptable answer to say, "I can't post an acceptable answer" and to refer people to some other place where they *can* find an answer.  That's what you were doing, referring people to another place to find an answer, and saying that you couldn't answer it yourself.  That the place you were linking to is just one of many possible links, or that it's content will change over time, doesn't change any of that.  (In fact, it just makes the problems that much worse).

Answer (score 0):

At ***best***, this question is answered [on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33531/why-improvising-your-own-hash-function-out-of-existing-hash-functions-is-so-bad).

At ***worst***, this question is incredibly open-ended and is basically a "did I do this right?" question.

There's no real reason for this question to remain open, and I'd want to encourage the OP to look at Security.SE to see if what they want to accomplish aligns with current industry methodologies.